# Product images not loading from correct source

Tags: magento-1.8, product-images

After a server update, my website seems to be loading my product images from

https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/300x/5a2864daa28c93cda65b9e6c099e84e6/p/r/website-cappuccino-image1_1.png

and it brings me to a 404 page when I open the image in a new tab.

that's what it shows when I inspect the image. I have cleared all cache from the cache management.
Not sure how to fix this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you Flush Catalog Images Cache?

Answer (score 0):

i think is a problem of folder permissions, whit this bash script you assign the best permisions to magento

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "664 files"
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
echo "775 folders"
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
chmod 777 -R var media
echo "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your server through putty and go to the magento root folder and then give full permission to your media folder by this following code.

```
chmod 777 -R media
```